# Opengl for Ubuntu14 (building QT 5.4)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, opengl, qt5

I have a fresh install of `Ubuntu 14 LTS` from this morning, I am using a PC with `Nvidia graphic cards` and I have successfully installed the latest version of the driver from the Nvidia website (`NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.30`).

I am trying to build `QT 5.4` (qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.4.2) and I am facing a problem with it not being able to find **opengl**.

I have installed the following packages in order to resolve all the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev build-essential libdbus-1-dev libfontconfig1-dev     libfreetype6-dev    libx11-dev    libxext-dev     libxfixes-dev    libxi-dev    libxrender-dev    libxcb1-dev    libx11-xcb-dev    libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev    libxcb-image0-dev    libxcb-shm0-dev    libxcb-icccm4-dev    libxcb-sync0-dev    libxcb-xfixes0-dev    libxcb-shape0-dev    libxcb-randr0-dev    libxcb-render-util0-dev
```

and finally:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

As far as I know the above should completely install the opengl packages for Ubuntu.

I then try to configure QT using the following command:

```
./configure -v -confirm-license -developer-build -opensource -xinput2 -dbus -opengl desktop -nomake examples -nomake tests)
```

I get the following error:

```
OpenGL auto-detection... ()
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIC  -I. -I../../../mkspecs/linux-g++ -o opengldesktop.o opengldesktop.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o opengldesktop opengldesktop.o   -lGL 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [opengldesktop] Error 1
OpenGL disabled.
The OpenGL functionality test failed!
 You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing
 QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL, QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL
```

I have searched for a while now and I can only assume that I have all the right packages installed but something is missing in the system path.
What can be missing and how do I add it to the system path?

The following output might help:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue on Debian 8.5: Nvidia driver + all libs recommended in [Building Qt5 from Git](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) installed but configure step of Qt 5.9 failed cause of missing OpenGL support.

Excerpt:

- Qt configure checks for openGL support by linking stuff against `libGL.so` - but the lib is missing
- `libGL.so` is provided by `libgl1-mesa-glx` that adds a symlink from `libGL.so` to `libGL.so.x.y.z` (in my case `libGL.so.1.2.0`)
- according to `dpkg`, `libGL.so.1.2.0` is also part of `libgl1-mesa-glx` - but missing for 'reasons'
- checking for other versions of `libGL.so` reveals that there is a library version installed by the Nvidia driver (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.35`)
- adding a symlink to this file solved the issue

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.35 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
  ```
- re-run `configure` using the flag `-recheck`

Step by step procedure (can also be applied to similar issues):

```
$ ./configure -opensource -confirm-license -recheck -v 1>dump 2>&1
...
> grep 'libGL.so.*No' dump

> /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: No such file or directory
> /usr/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot open /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so: No such file or directory

$ ls -l /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 19  2015 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.2.0
```

*libGL.so.1.2.0* is missing, check for provider...

```
$ dpkg -S libGL.so.1.2.0
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0

$ dpkg -l libgl1-mesa-glx
...
||/ Name                                     Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-========================================-=========================-=========================-=====================================================================================
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                    10.3.2-1+deb8u1           amd64                     free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
```

So `libgl1-mesa-glx` library is installed but the `libGL.so.1.2.0` is missing in the path. Check for other `libGL.so*` files...

```
$ find /usr/lib -name libGL.so*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.35
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1
```

The `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.35` is the only valid openGL lib on my box (was installed by the Nvidia driver installer).

Solution:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.346.35 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt 5.9.
First I ran the **configure** when the **libgl1-mesa-dev** and **libglu1-mesa-dev** were not installed. After that I installed these libgl* libraries. But the error "OpenGL not found" remained. The error disappeared after the current uncompressed directory was deleted and the archive was unpacked again.

Comment: You don't need to unpack it again, gust delete the `config.cache` file

Answer (score 0):

the following detects Desktop OpenGL on Mint 17.3 32-bit system with Nvidia card and proprietary drivers.
/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure --prefix=/root/work/qt5_setup/qt_install -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-clang-libc++

platforms options can be found in
/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/mkspecs

Before above install clang (C, C++ and Objective-C compiler (LLVM based)) and libc++-dev (LLVM C++ Standard library (development files))

LLVM is a collection of libraries and tools that make it easy to build compilers, optimizers, just-in-time code generators, and many other compiler-related programs.

Whereas
/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure --prefix=/root/work/qt5_setup/qt_install -opensource -confirm-license

with default platform options (linux-g++ linux-g++-32) didn't find Desktop OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

The below solution failed for me at later stage with clang-c++ unable to compile qt source properly.So posting another solution using g++ compiler itself.

The following steps detects Desktop OpenGL on Mint 17.3 32-bit system with Nvidia card and proprietary drivers.
in file
/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/mkspecs/common/linux.conf 
which is included by
/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf

environment variables must be set to:

QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL     =   "/usr/include/GL"
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL     =   "/usr/lib/"
QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $$QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $$QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL

QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL       = -lGL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2   = -lGLESv2

The libGL used points to Nvidia driver provided library in my system.
/usr/lib/libGL.so -> /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.390.48

Whereas 
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
to Mesa3D provided library.

Also make sure mesa-common-dev, libglu1-mesa-dev, libgl1-mesa-dev and other OpenGL development packages are installed.

/root/work/qt5_setup/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure --prefix=/root/work/qt5_setup/qt_install -opensource -confirm-license -platform linux-g++ && make -j 5

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `config.cache` file in Qt directory (the same one that contains the `configure` script), and try again.